# Filtering by an array in D3 (filtering by array of string keywords)

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, filter

I'm attempting to filter data points on a map by whether certain keywords are present in the data properties.  For example, filtering points by music genre, i.e. display all points whose "Genre" property contains any one of these keywords: "Rock", "Pop", "Indie".

It's almost working, but I can't quite get the D3 filter method to work on an array.  Here's an example:

```
//When "Rock Genre" radio button is instantiated, display only "Rock" events
d3.selectAll("#rockPopGenre").on("change", function() {
resetDisplay()
display = this.checked ? "none" : "#ffba00";
display2 = this.checked ? "none" : "black";
x = ["Rock","Pop","Indie"]
genreMatch(x)            
});


//Genre matching function which filters points based on an array of key-words
function genreMatch (genreType) {
var genreType

for (i=0; i<genreType.length; i++){
    d3.selectAll(".events")
.filter(function(d) {       
    return (!d.Genre.includes(genreType[i]))
})
.style("fill", display)
.style("stroke", display2)
}  
}
```

Example of d.Genre:

```
"Genre": "Standup, Comedy Rock, Comedy, Standup Comedy, Funny, Humor"
"Genre": "Genres: Alternative Rock, Alternative, Pop"
"Genre": "Indie, Indie Electronic, Rock, Alternative"
```

The above method only partially works.  For example, it only displays points which contain the keyword "Rock", but will exclude points which contain "Pop". I want to filter the data based on ALL keywords: i.e. if d.Genre contains either "Rock", "Pop", or "Indie" in the string, display those points, and hide the points that don't meet that criteria.

I'm not quite sure how to achieve this.  I believe the problem is that the code is filtering each keyword in the array separately, rather than treating the array as an group of words to match.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you filtering on the `d.Genre` not including `genreType[i]`? What does `d.Genre` look like? Can you post a minimal example?

Comment: I'm filter on "not including" because I'm setting the display to "non" for those points that don't meet key-word criteria .

Answer (score 0):

You can change the opacity property on the event depending on the filter as such:

```
d3.selectAll(".events").attr('opacity', d => {   
   const includes = genreType.filter(item => d.Genre.indexOf(item) !== -1)
   return includes ? 1 : 0
})
```

this will work on the assumptions that d.Genre is a string as such `"Standup, Comedy Rock, Comedy, Standup Comedy, Funny, Humor"` and genreType is an array of keywords as such: `["Standup", "Comedy"]`.

Of the genreType is another string you should execute a split as such `.split(/, ?/g)` in order to convert it